# Null when injecting SpringSecurityService into Filter in Grails

Tags: grails

I'm trying to use SpringSecurityService in a filter to get currently logged in user. The problem is that I got null and cannot get the current user.

```
class ApplicationFilters {

   def springSecurityService

   def filters = {
      all(controller:'*', action:'*') {

         after = { Map model ->

            def userName=springSecurityService.currentUser
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I tried also to get params map from the filter and I got also null. What should I do to solve this?

Thanks,

Comment: I've noticed that in my services, dependency injection doesn't work on a dynamic reload of the code - I need to kill the Grails process and restart it.  I was getting similar NPEs that I couldn't figure out. Perhaps it's the same for you?

Comment: Try removing `Map model ->` from the code. Other than that my code is exactly the same.

Comment: @JasonNichols I can confirm this. It seems like dependency injection is not working on dynamic reload of code.

Answer (score 0):

don't know if you've solved this issue yet, but you can definitely call your `Service` within the `*Filters` class by referring to the injected `applicationContext` like this:

```
class TestFilters {
  def filters = {
    all(controller:'*', action:'*') {
        before = {
            applicationContext.testService.serviceMethod()
        }
        after = { Map model ->

        }
        afterView = { Exception e ->

        }
    }
  }
}
```